# I need to program alarms in my Flutter App

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello i'm developing an Flutter App and i need to program alarms in that.

I already try with Alarm_Manager and Alarm_Clock but the examples is confuse to me, i tried to implement it but doesn't work, if someone have an alternative or someone can help me to implement Alarm_Manager i'll be grateful.
Thanks

Comment: android_alarm_manager 0.4.1+8 developed by flutter team. you can use that.

Comment: I already tried with that but the example results very confuse to me, did you implement it before?